# Parsing a formatted string with RegEx or similar

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, text-parsing

I have an application which sends a TCP message to a server, and gets one back.

The message it gets back is in this format:

> 0,"120"1,"Data Field 1"2,"2401"3,"Data Field 3"1403-1,"multiple
>   occurence 1"1403-2,"multiple occurence 2"99,""

So basically it is a set of fields concatenated together.
Each field has a tag, a comma, and a value - in that order.
The tag is the number, the value is in quotes, the comma seperates them.
0,"120"
0 is the tag, 120 is the value.

A complete message always starts with a 0 field and ends with 99,"" field.

To complicate things, some tags have dashes because they are split into more than 1 value. 
The order of the numbers is not significant.

(For reference, this is a "Fedex Tagged Transaction" message).

So I'm looking for a decent way of validating that we have a "complete" message (ie has the 0 and 99 fields) - because it's from a TCP message I guess I have to account for not having received the full message yet.
Then splitting it up to get all the values I need.

The best I have come up with is for parsing is some poor regex and some cleaning-up afterwards.
The heart of it is this: **(\d?\d?\d?\d?-?\d?\d,")** to split it

```
string s = @"(\d?\d?\d?\d?-?\d?\d,"")";
string[] strArray = Regex.Split(receivedData, r);

Assert.AreEqual(14, strArray.Length, "Array length should be 14", since we have 7 fields.);

Dictionary<string, string> fields = new Dictionary<string, string>();

//Now put it into a dictionary which should be easier to work with than an array
for (int i = 0; i <= strArray.Length-2; i+=2)
{
    fields.Add(strArray[i].Trim('"').Trim(','), strArray[i + 1].Trim('"'));
}
```

Which doesn't really work.
It has a lot of quotes and commas left over, and doesn't seem particularly well-formed...
I'm not good with Regex so I can't put together what I need it to do.

I don't even know if it is the best way.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use Regex.Matches rather than Regex.Split.  This way you can iterate over all the matches, and use capture groups to just grab the data you want directly, while still maintaining structure.  I provided a regex that should work for this below in the example:

```
        MatchCollection matchlist = Regex.Matches(receivedData, @"(?<tag>\d+(?:-\d+)?),""(?<data>.*?)""");
        foreach (Match match in matchlist)
        {
            string tag = match.Groups["tag"].Value;
            string data = match.Groups["data"].Value;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this expression

```
\d*(-\d*)?,"[^"]*"
```

Match count: 7

```
0,"120"
1,"Data Field 1"
2,"2401"
3,"Data Field 3"
1403-1,"multiple occurence 1"
1403-2,"multiple occurence 2"
99,""
```